# Find intersecting points on rectangle edges for line drawn inside it

Tags: geometry, intersection, rectangles, square

1. Draw a rectangle ABCD.
2. Draw a line inside it connecting any two edges GF.
3. Draw a perpendicular bisector to line GF.

At what points does the perpendicular bisector intersect the edges of the rectangle?

In the following image, line GF is drawn from (0, 2) to (6, 0). I need to know where does the perpendicular bisector intersects the rectangle on AB and CD.

Line inside rectangle

[image: Line inside rectangle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Middle point of GF

```
M.X = (G.X + F.X) / 2
M.Y = (G.Y + F.Y) / 2
```

Perpendicular vector to GF

```
D.X = G.Y - F.Y
D.Y = F.X - G.X
```

Parametric equation of bisector

```
X = M.X + t * D.X
Y = M.Y + t * D.Y
```

Solve these equations for `X = XLeft, X = XRight, Y = YTop, Y = YBottom`, and you'll get intersection points

For example, at first you solve equation `XLeft = M.X + t * D.X` to find parameter t for intersection point with the left edge of rectangle.

Then check if `Y' = M.Y + t * D.Y` is in range (`YTop..YBottom`) for t found.

If yes, then bisector intersects the left edge in point (XLeft, Y')

Comment: thanks for reply, but I don't get what does ( t ) mean in that final equation. Also please explain what X = XBottom, X = XTop, Y = YLeft, Y = YRight mean and how I get my respective co-ordinates. If possible explain it with example. Thanks again.

Comment: t is unknown parameter. I corrected names: `X = XLeft` means that you solve equation `XLeft = M.X + t * D.X` to find parameter t for intersection point with the left edge of rectangle and check if `Y = M.Y + t * D.Y` is in range (YTop..YBottom) for this t.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer